# Perl cookie problem

Tags: perl, cookies

I wrote an http session manager on perl, the session manager has to write cookies to the user browser, when I test it on firefox 4, it works fine, and cookies are written to the browser, chrome and IE seem to reject cookies for some reason, I made an invistagation but no use, my cookies appear like this:

Set-`Cookie:session=nSwbgFp5suScOMjmDMVNxv4EQLJpDat7YanRJGfM3hrvbjCCprUvocU4HxiR4Tk_VUAV6hE68zlriRvX0CeC4Ytk1DJc8IhCn_4C;expires=Sat, 14-May-2011 10:10:56 GMT`

Something I noticed, if I configure the cookies to expire in 1 day. it work for all browser, but an hour it wont work for IE and chrome.
If anyone has an idea about how to sniff cookies in IE or chrome, let me know . I don't mean using a network sniffer. Since I'm sure that cookies are emitted to browser . What  I mean that something related to browsers.

thanks in advance.

---

```
my ($key, $value) = @_;
my (@cookies, $k, $v, $r, $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst);
my @chars = ('a' .. 'z', 'A' .. 'Z', '0' .. '9', '_');
my @weekday = ('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
my @month = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
$r = '';
foreach (1 .. 100) {$r .= $chars[rand @chars]}
## Calculate the expiration date of the session
($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst) = gmtime(time() + $::session_life);
$year = $year + 1900;
$mon  = $month[$mon];
$wday = $weekday[$wday];

## Generate cookies
print("Set-Cookie:$::session_cookie_name=$r;" . "expires=$wday, $mday-$mon-$year $hour:$min:$sec GMT;\n");
```

Comment: Show some minimal code that exhibits the problem so that interested people can reproduce it on their own.

Answer (score 0):

- In Chromium, Menu → Tools → Developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+I).
- In Opera, Menu → Page → Developer tools → Dragonfly (Ctrl+Shift+I).
- For Internet Explorer, see [Developer Toolbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Developer_Toolbar).

---

The time calculation is wrong. Use the library [CGI::Cookie](http://p3rl.org/CGI%3a%3aCookie) to generate a standard conforming cookie header.

```
use CGI qw();
use CGI::Cookie qw();

my $cgi                 = CGI->new;
my $session_cookie_name = …;
my $r                   = …;

print $cgi->header(
    -type   => 'text/plain',
    -cookie => CGI::Cookie->new(
        -name    => $session_cookie_name,
        -value   => $r,
        -expires => '+2h',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks Daxim, this will not intercept cookies, this will show cookies accepted by browser.

Comment: Daxim, this will not show cookies coming to browser, it'll show only cookies stored by browser,and usually they aren't there.

Comment: Ahmad J. Hamad, you are mistaken. Did you actually try that out what I said? The developer tools for each browser show the network traffic as seen by the browser, including cookies/headers. I think you are confusing this with the browsers' cookie store for some reason. - Adding a screenshot.

Comment: Hi Daxim, yes, I understand what you mean, and I tried it, cookies don't show there, I'm not sure why, but the strange thing is that if I put the expire to a short time, like within 2 hours it never works, if I put it to a day it works without any problem, I've refered back to the RFCs that are related to session management and cookies, but no time constraints are mentioned there.

Comment: Hi Daxim,
Here is my code:
 my ($key,$value)=@_;
 my (@cookies,$k,$v,$r,$sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst);
 my @chars=('a'..'z','A'..'Z','0'..'9','_');
 my @weekday = ('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
 my @month=('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');

 $r='';
  foreach(1..100){$r.=$chars[rand @chars]}
  ## Calculate the expiration date of the session
  ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=
     gmtime(time()+$::session_life);
  $year=$year+1900;
  $mon=$month[$mon];
  $wday=$weekday[$wday];

Comment: ## Generate cookies
  print("Set-Cookie:$::session_cookie_name=$r;".
        "expires=$wday, $mday-$mon-$year $hour:$min:$sec GMT;\n");

Comment: thanks Daxim,
Can you show me whats wrong with the time calculation? I never wanted to use the CGI module, I always try to minimize using modules in my code, I try to depend on code I write.
if you show me the bug in my code, please.

Comment: Numeric values must be zero-padded to achieve fixed length, [see RFC 6265 §4.1.1.](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1).